# making a script search for a file, then read the file if found. python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

idk whats wrong here, kinda just wont work.
so I have an installer script called setup.py, and it installs the directories. but, it also makes a file called setup.txt that will tell the main script not to try to install it again. But it doesn't do anything wether I have the setup.txt file or not.
any help would be appreciated.

````
import time
import os
import setup
import glob


def install_checker():
    setup_file = open("setup.txt","r")
    install_checker = setup_file.readline(24)

    if install_checker == "setup completion = true":
          pass
    else:
        setup.setup()

mydir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(mydir)
for file in glob.glob("setup.txt"):
    print(file)

    if file == "setup.txt":
        install_checker()
    else:
        setup.setup()```
````

Comment: Just try to read the file. If it throws an error, the file doesn't exist. If you get no error, it does.

Comment: also use `with open(...) as setup_file` so that it'll close the file when you're done reading it

Comment: Put in some `print` statements to understand which lines of code are being executed.

Comment: I think that it does not work because when using setup_file.readline(24) the return looks like : "setup completion = true\n". Maybe is that the cause for not doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check if a file exists. Here's one:

```
if os.path.isfile("setup.txt"):
    setup.setup()
else:
    install_checker()
```

I would not recommend trying to open the file and catching the error because the file may exist but not be readable.